# 1986 Dodge D150 dies while driving

Tags: engine, dodge, stall

While idling or even driving, the truck will die as if the key was turned off. Sometimes it will start right back up, but more often it will not.

When it does not start right back up,I notice no power to dash lights or the dome light, no clicks, no turning over...nothing. If I let it sit for a while (hours at a time) it will start.

Being an older truck, the doors are hard to close fully, but closing the drivers door seems to cause this a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a broken wire / corroded connection somewhere.

Start by making sure the battery terminals are clean and tight.

Then check systematically all the other main cable connections battery to fuse box, battery to main supplies : ignition switch etc.

Without the "non start" issue I would have suggested a faulty coil , but it sounds like a connection or broken cable. Even the main battery / starter cables can be broken - if they have been vibrating for years...